# Bootstrap Tooltip Functionality in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, electron, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using Bootstrap with Electron, and I'm trying to use the included tooltip functionality.  When I run the page as a 'traditional' web page, the tooltip works (using Chrome).  When I run it in Electron, it does not work, and just appears as a title type mouse-over.  Code:

```
<button id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Button</button>
```

Then

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");});
```

I have found a [reference](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8025) to Electron not supporting "Native popovers and Tooltips" - I took that to mean that I needed to provide the required js support to make the tooltips work.  How do I get tooltips in Electron?  And if standard bootstrap JS is not functional in electron, can someone explain why so I can be aware when looking to bring in other JS controls/libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer when examining some other features that weren't working but should have.  While I didn't find any reference to this in the bootstrap documentation, it appears as if jquery was not initializing.  I amended the jquery import as follows:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" onload="window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;"></script>
```

Now Bootstrap tooltips work as expected.